# Jackson with JAXB - abstract types instantiation

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson

I'm facing problem with Jackson's ObjectMapper using JAXB annotations. To be concrete, I'm having collection with interface generic information and although I can deserialize input from XML, it is not possible with Jackson (using JAXB introspector). Maybe I'm just missing some configuration property or JAXB annotation? The problem is that "abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information", I thought @XmlElementRef (or @XmlElement) with type information will handle this problem, but obviosly it does not.

Please note, that I want to stay only with JAXB annotations if possible.
E.g. using @JsonTypeInfo or @JsonDeserialize would be the last thing to do.

IEntry.java:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Entry.class)
public interface IEntry {
    String getValue();
}
```

Entry.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
public class Entry implements IEntry {

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    String value;

    public Entry() {
    }

    public Entry(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Aggregator.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "aggregator")
public class Aggregator {

    @XmlElementRef(type = Entry.class)
    private Set<IEntry> entries;

    public Aggregator() {
    }

    public Aggregator(Set<IEntry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public Set<IEntry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test
    public void testSerialization() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        AnnotationIntrospector intr = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
        om.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(intr);

        String json = "{\"entries\":[{\"value\":\"X\"},{\"value\":\"Y\"},{\"value\":\"Z\"}]}\";\n}";
        Aggregator agr = om.readValue(json, Aggregator.class);
    }
```

Thanks for all response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;  

@JsonDeserialize(as = Entry.class)
public interface IEntry {
   String getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this but I noted that i prefer staying only with JAXB annotations if possible:-)

Comment: Only JAXB annotations it's impossible

Comment: Ok, I will wait for a while and if no-one else answers, I will mark ur answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I am not sure if Jackson supports this use case or not, but you appear to be using `@XmlElementRef` incorrectly.  When you use `@XmlElementRef` the root element name associated with the class is used to determine the instance to be instantiated.  If your example the node `entries` does not match the `@XmlRootElement(name="entry")` annotation.

You could try one of the following options (they all work with MOXy's JSON binding, see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html):

**OPTION 1 - Change `@XMLRootElement` on `Entry`**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entries")
public class Entry implements IEntry {

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    String value;

    public Entry() {
    }

    public Entry(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**OPTION #2 - Change the JSON Document**

```
{"entry":[{"value":"X"},{"value":"Y"},{"value":"Z"}]}}
```

**OPTION #3 - Use `@XMLElement` instead of `@XMLElementRef`**

If you use the `@XmlElement` annotation you can specify on the field/property what the node name should be instead of relying on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.  Also if you annotate the fields you should specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at the type level.

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "aggregator")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Aggregator {

    @XmlElement(type = Entry.class)
    private Set<IEntry> entries;

    public Aggregator() {
    }

    public Aggregator(Set<IEntry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public Set<IEntry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using it in JAX-RS REST service - implementation RestEasy (running on JBoss). Anyway option #3 did not help (the same exception with abstract type). Option #2: I'd like to use same object for both ser./deser., so I cannot simply change just JSON side while it has to be connected. And option #1 would differ XML output.

Comment: @d1x - Jackson isn't a JAXB (JSR-222) compliant implementation so you are not guaranteed how it will interpret the standard JAXB annotations   (this is why option 3 probably doesn't work).  If you are interested in how MOXy could be leveraged for your use case, then you may find the following answer helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519572/can-i-get-moxy-to-not-output-an-attribute-when-generating-json